# How to call stored procedure in zend1 with doctrine1

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine, zend-db-table, doctrine-odm, doctrine-query

Please help me :

I want to call mysql stored procedure in zend1 by doctrine1

My stored procedure is  :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test()
BEGIN
  SELECT 'Number of records: ', count(*) from user;
END//
```

stored procedure working fine in phpMyAdmin.

But How to call this stored procedure in doctrine1 by zend1

This one is simple query of the doctrine

```
$data = Doctrine_Query::create ()->select ( "u.id" )->from ( 'user u' )->fetchArray ();
```

But I want to call sp_test() stored procedure in code .

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use plain pdo to call stored procedures. To do that you must do something like this:

```
$dbh = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection()->getDbh();
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('BEGIN sp_test(); END;')
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Basically I'm not sure what DB engine you're using. In above example it is an Oracle way of calling stored procedures but what goes as a `prepare` argument is a pure sql, so you can put almost anything there. Also note, that above example uses prepared statement - if you don't need it you can use following code (`$sql` variable holds your whatever sql code):

```
$conn = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection();
$conn->execute($sql);
```

Comment: Then you should probably use mysql specific sql to call procedure - as far as I know it would look something like `call sp_test();`